# Text label of UITableViewCell is blurred

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a grouped `uitableview` with a **row height for each cell = 250 (very large)** when I put any text in the text label of its cells, the text is blurred, however, when I reduce the height the text font gets sharper and clearer, I increased the font size but it stays blurred.
what is the solution to this problem ?

thanks so much in advance.

EDIT: code of the custom cell text label:

```
  - (void)layoutSubviews {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   CGRect textLabelFrame = [[self textLabel] frame];
    textLabelFrame.origin.x = 102;
    textLabelFrame.origin.y  = 2;
    textLabelFrame.size.width = 185;
    textLabelFrame.size.height = 120;
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0 ];
self.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[[self textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:113/256.0 green:113/256.0   blue:113/256.0 alpha:100.0] ];
self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
  }
```

Comment: put your code here when u stuck

Comment: Can you add a Label to the tableView and set the fonts of that?

Comment: @ Akshay: I think I can do it, but this cell is re-used multiple times in the project, and a change like this will affect many parts of the project

Comment: Is it possible that you have set `shouldRasterize` to YES on the cell's backing CALayer? Doing so without setting an appropriate `rasterizationScale` would cause this on devices with retina displays.

Comment: @ Mark: i did not set such property

Comment: @ Akshay: I've tried your approach, it makes the label less blurry but it's still little blurry not as sharp as it should

Comment: @MarkAdams: Magical fix, thanks! My symptoms were blurry texts and lines, occurred only on physical device(which according to Mark is completely logical). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are laying out any of the subviews of the UITableViewCells programmatically, make sure that the subviews have integer coordinates (i.e. round the positions to the nearest integer).

Comment: I use a custom cell and as you said, I layoutSubviews with integer coordinates, I played with these coordinates and sizes but nothing changed, the text is still blurred. look at Edit above

Comment: This is most likely the cause of the blurriness in the text. Without a definite (whole) coordinate the text may render incorrectly causing undesirable aesthetics

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related, but it looks odd to me

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:113/256.0 green:113/256.0   blue:113/256.0 alpha:100.0]
```

Can you try the following instead :

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:113.0/255.0 green:113.0/255.0   blue:113.0/256.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Let me know how that goes ?

Comment: I've tried it but without any new result. by the way, I have used the same custom cell in another tableViewController with rowHeight for each cell = 49 (not too large), everything is OK in this case, but the problem comes in when I increase the rowHeight to 250 in a grouped UITableView